# How can I import Python module located in S3 when running Spark job in AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

My team has a cloud process like this:

- run Databricks work flow that kicks off Spark job
- Spark job will run a Python script located in s3 path

I want that Python script to "import" a custom module. I can use common modules such as "import boto3", but if I import my own custom module it says it can't find it.

It seems Spark doesn't just look in the same s3 path as it would on your local machine.

Is it possible to "import" a Python module specifying an S3 path?